# Apache reverse proxy with GSUITE authentication and check OPENLDAP user member of specific group

Tags: php, apache, reverse-proxy, google-workspace

I created a PHP login page with GSUITE authentication.
After GSuite authentication (because I can't authenticate users for group), I check if the user is member of specific OPENLDAP group, if not I force redirect to login page.
Now I need for all user authenticated and are member of specific OPENLDAP group to allow access to back-end server using Apache reverse proxy authentication, but I need two step authentication:

> 1. The user must be authenticated by GSUITE;
> 2. The user must be member of the specific OPENLDAP group.

Now for the first step I solved in this way:

```
<VirtualHost backend.mydomain.local:8443>
        ServerName backend.mydomain.local

        SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
        SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
        SSLHonorCipherOrder On
        SSLCompression off

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mySSL.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mySSL.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/backend_8443_error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/backend_8443_access.log combined

        OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
        OIDCClientID xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
        OIDCClientSecret xxxxx
        OIDCRedirectURI https://backend.mydomain.local:8443/index.php
        OIDCScope "profile openid"
        OIDCCryptoPassphrase example@3003
        OIDCCookiePath /
        OIDCAuthNHeader X-Forwarded-User
        OIDCRemoteUserClaim sub
        OIDCClaimPrefix example_
        OIDCSessionInactivityTimeout 1800

        <Location />
                AuthType openid-connect
                Require valid-user
        </Location>

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.20:5563/ connectiontimeout=1800 timeout=1800
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.20:5563/
</VirtualHost>
```

But how can I check if the user is member of specific OPENLDAP group when the user digit directly the url in the browser: **backend.mydomain.local:8443**

Thanks for the support.
Marco